# ScheduledExecutorService - cancel return Theard to Thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using this code to maintains ping and later notify reading for my program.

```
scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
pingHandler = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate([command], 5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
notifyHandler = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate([command], 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

After:

```
pingHandler.cancel(true);
```

Can I do again:

```
pingHandler = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate([command], 5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

?
Will it work? Or there will be no more free threads in pool?

Comment: Well, from reading the documentation ... it should work. Just wondering: why don't you just try? It seems like you already got most of the code together, what prevents you from writing a bunch of unit tests to see what actually happens?

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work, but i don't know if it is correct solution and if it will not create some problems in future.

Comment: As said; the documentation is pretty clear. It says that "cancel" "ends" a task. And it says that the fixed thread pool will always allow for two threads. Together with passing tests; that sounds like "high chance of being correct". On the other hand, its multi-threading; which always has potential for surprises.

Comment: So, i will go with it. I just wanted to ask, because someone may have bigger knowledge. Thank you for response.